# How to manage chargebacks and refunds

Tags: facebook, facebook-payments

I would like to find a smart way for managing refunds and chargebacks with the new local currency systeme with chargeback/refunds callbacks.

We're having users that understood that they can spend a awesome lot of money, get their things on the game (coins and such), play their heartfull for about three days and then demand chargebacks that they obtain automatically.

We even had someone spend 2000$ and get a refund a month and a half later.

Maybe I have missed something but I don't see a way of contesting these refunds (users have used what they bought and then left the game before getting their money back so we can't really do something like resetting their account).

Is there a legal way ? Is there a technical way to prevent chargebacks when they're not legitimate ?

Thanks for you input.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about contracts with payment providers. Stack Overflow is for programming-related questions.

Comment: There may be a programming related answer. I'm all for that too. Especially if there is something I don't understand about chargeback/refund callbacks and maybe a way to inform facebook that they must be denied by the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a documentation (if you don't know it already) about the dispute process here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/disputesrefunds/

They recomment to use Realtime Updates to track what payments are done, disputes etc.: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/realtimeupdates/#rccr